# How do I hide a custom button that I add to a UITabBar?

Tags: ios, swift

```
    availableButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, screenHeight - tabBarHeight!, CGFloat(screenWidth/5.0) * 2.0, tabBarHeight!)
    availableButton.backgroundColor = FlatGreen()
    availableButton.setTitle("Turn On", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    availableButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    availableButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Bold", size: 20.0)
    self.view.addSubview(availableButton)
```

This is the button that I added to my `TabBarViewController`.

When I hide my Tab Bar:

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true
```

I want this button to be hidden as well.

My button is the width of 2 tab bar items.

[image]

Comment: you are adding this button on self.view, so hiding tabbar wont hide the button on main view

Comment: @Racheel, where can I add it to then?

Comment: show us some design, what do you wanna acheive, meanwhile you can make instance of this button and hide it as well when hiding your tabbar

Comment: or you can add your button to the tabbar view not self.view, so when hiding its subviews will also hide

Comment: @RaheelSadiq how do I add it to the tab bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let tabBarContext = UnsafeMutablePointer<()>()`

`self.tabBar.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "hidden", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context:tabBarContext)`

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if context == tabBarContext && keyPath == "hidden"{
        let newChange = change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as! Int
        self.availableButton.hidden  = (newChange == 1) ? true :false   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have added this button to your view, perhaps this is very bad approach to work.

```
self.view.addSubview(availableButton)
```

as tabbar is behind it so it shows.
Either ad this to tabbar by using tabBarItem or hide this button manually

```
availableButton.hidden = YES;
```

Your problem will be solved.Thank you

Comment: This. Additional, if you want to hide the `tabBar` at several places, write a new method on your controller which is doing the work and just call this method, maybe with a parameter(hiding/showing). This will prevent you from forgetting to hide the button for example.

Comment: Is it possible to add the button to the TabBar instead of self.view?

Comment: Yes you can use tabBarItem instead of uibutton it work to move to anyother ViewController

Comment: @baydi, how do I do that? Can you take a look at my screenshot?

Comment: UIViewController *view1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *view2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    

    NSMutableArray *tabViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tabViewControllers addObject:view1];
    [tabViewControllers addObject:view2];
   
    [self setViewControllers:tabViewControllers];
   
    view1.tabBarItem = 
      [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"view1" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"view1"] tag:1];
    view2.tabBarItem =  [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"view2" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"view3"] tag:2];

Comment: You can add UITabBarController from story board that is much easy your programatical work will be reduce by it

Comment: @baydi my button is twice the width of a normal tab bar item

Comment: u can change the image size or set the tabbaritem contest